# Importance of compact operators for numerical approximation of integral equations?

Tags: numerical-methods, operator-theory, compact-operators, integral-equations

I was recently attended some talks on numerical approaches to integral equations. From what I gather, if an operator in the integral equation is not compact it leads to problems numerically. An example being in the case of a domain with a corner - this leads to an integral equation with a non-compact operator and is supposedly a tougher problem to handle than a domain with a smooth boundary.

One thing I didn't pick up at the talks, is why specifically are problems with non-compact operators tougher to handle numerically? I believe it has something to do with the spectrum not being discrete in the case of non-compactness but I'd really like some clarification on the precise difficulties of handling non-compact operators numerically?

Comment: "Compact" in general implies "finitely approximable". A compact set allows for $ε$-nets, a compact operator can be approximated by operators of finite-dimensional rank. This is important as any computer is finite, and can thus only compute approximations of finite data size.